# SwiftUI and MapKit on macOS, issue of screen to location conversion with toolbar

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

**My goal**
aving a Map view on a macOS app created with SwiftUI, which needs both a toolbar and a status bar, I wants to be able to clic on the map to add an annotation at a user's chosen location.

**My issue**
The sample code I use works if I have no toolbar and status bar. When I have them, there is an offset in coordinates that I don't understand how to solve.

**Sample code**
How can I fix the following sample code to have accurate management of the mouse location when adding an annotation in that context?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MyPoint: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var points: [MyPoint] = [MyPoint]()
    @State var status: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0){
            MapReader { mapReader in
                Map {
                    ForEach(points) { point in
                        Annotation(point.name, coordinate: point.location) {
                            Text("╳")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold(true)
                                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                .mapControlVisibility(.visible)
                .mapStyle(.imagery)
                .mapControls({
                    MapCompass()
                    MapUserLocationButton()
                    MapScaleView()
                })
                .onContinuousHover(coordinateSpace: .local, perform: { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .active(let cGPoint):
                        if let coordinates = mapReader.convert(cGPoint, from: .local) {
                            status = "screen \(cGPoint.x), \(cGPoint.y) - loc \(coordinates.latitude), \(coordinates.longitude)"
                        } else {
                            status = ""
                        }
                    case .ended:
                        status = ""
                    }
                })
                .onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local, perform: { screenCoord in
                    if let location = mapReader.convert(screenCoord, from: .local) {
                        points.append(.init(name: "screen click: \(screenCoord.x), \(screenCoord.y)\nloc \(location.latitude), \(location.longitude)", location: location))
                    }
                })
                .toolbar {
                    Text("A toolbar is needed")
                }
            }
            Text(status)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)

        }
    }
}
```